# Complex ListView item layout with all elements the same size for each item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to build a complex listview item layout with all of the elements being the same dimensions for each listview item with the entire layout taking up the whole width of the screen. So far I have attempted doing this using a linearlayout and found that this is the wrong approach. I have then attempted using a relative layout however this has not worked for me so I hope that someone can point out how I can make this work.

Here is a diagram of what I am trying to build.
[image: ListView Item Layout]

Here is some more details about the diagram:

- Only elements 5 and 6 have the same content for every list item. The
  rest of elements all will have different text however the layout
  should always be the same size.
- Element 4 should only be 2 lines. Elements 1, 2 and 3 should only be 1
  line.
- Element 2 should be aligned left and element 3 should be aligned
  right.
- Element 2 and 3 should each be half of the width of element 4.

Here is my attempt at this layout using a RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="2dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtRaceNumber"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRaceName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtRaceNumber"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRaceClass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtRaceNumber" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRaceStartTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtRaceClass" />
     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnTracklist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:paddingRight="8dip"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtRaceStartTime" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/go"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnTracklist" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Using this RelativeLayout all of the elements appear scrambled within the layout.

How can I get all of these elements to align as I have shown in the Diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get the desired layout using weightSum on the main layout.

Here is the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/twolinechecked"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:maxHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:paddingTop="2dip"
android:paddingBottom="2dip"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtRaceNumber"
    android:layout_width="40dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRaceName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearTextInner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtRaceClass"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtRaceStartTime"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnTracklist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="8dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/go"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Good I guess its same structure what I have mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Follow below structure I feel you can achieve what you want use weight and weightSum.

```
<LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout>
    <TextView/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
    <TextView/>
    <LinearLayout orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView/>
    <TextView/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton/>
    <ImageView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.15" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.15" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have edited the answer I got the desired layout please set id and other details as I have skipped it

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRaceNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TExt1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lin1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lin3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRaceName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtRaceClass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="text2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtRaceStartTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="text3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnTracklist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:paddingRight="8dip" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No... I need a single layout that can be used as a ListView Item and displays like the diagram that I have posted.

Comment: I think even this can be used as a listview item which can be inflated.

Comment: Hi Sharath, sorry but I tried it and it does not work. I have posted the working version.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
           />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```